# Laravel artisan migrate

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I'm working on a site with the latest version of laravel, and we have recently changed the MySQL DB location from a remote host to a local host. After moving and editing the config/database.php file to reflect the changes, I tried to run the command php artisan migrate, but I'm not getting anything back.

There is no response on the terminal, and no results in the new database. I've also tried migrate:refresh and migrate:status.

How do I re-run the migrations and get the tables in the new database?

Comment: `php artisan migrate` should do the trick. You should be able to do a backup of the remote MySQL and restore it in the local instance so you don't have any data loss.

Comment: import database from local export in remote......

Comment: So php artisan migrate and all the commands under migrate seem to just sit at the terminal and not actually do anything. I know this used to work when we were on the old DB, but not sure what we did to break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first drop your database table or tables and than execute

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

hopefully it'll work for you

Comment: I'm running these commands on a fresh database with no tables. Should I create a table and then drop it?

Comment: at first create a DB then migrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just export DB to a file and import it on a local host. You do not need to run php artisan migrate command.

You do not want to run migrations if you already have DB with tables and data.